# Using ted (or another package) instead of etoolbox for patching commands in memoir?

Tags: memoir, etoolbox, patching

Another question related to my university's odd ToC style requirements. Regular chapters in the ToC need to have all-caps titles, and appendices need regular-case titles. I have a perfectly elegant etoolbox solution

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}%
{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}}%
{\let\f@rtocold\f@rtoc%
 \def\f@rtoc{\uppercase\expandafter{\f@rtocold}}%
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}}%
{\typeout{Chapter Patch Succeeded}}%
{\typeout{Chapter Patch Failed}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{One}
This is chapter 1.
\appendix
\chapter{Alpha}
This is appendix A.
\end{document}
```

but it seems PCTeX 6 doesn't have e-TeX support built in (waiting on registration at the PCTeX forums so I can ask about that directly). I don't use it myself, but some people here do, and I'd like to avoid having them change TeX systems if possible.

I can't use memoir's built-in `\patchcommand`, since `\@chapter` has delimited arguments. I've tried using `\Substitute*` from `ted`, but no success yet. Replacing the commands between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` above with the following:

```
\usepackage{ted}
\Substitute*[\renewcommand{\@chapter}]{\@chapter}%
{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}}%
{\let\f@rtocold\f@rtoc%
 \def\f@rtoc{\uppercase\expandafter{\f@rtocold}}%
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}}
```

I get `Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.` How can I convince `\Substitute*` to modify a command with arguments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `\@chapter` takes (delimited) arguments, we need to write them explicitly. `\Substitute*` expands `\@chapter[#1]{#2}` to the replacement text of `\@chapter` with the correct arguments. It then replaces `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}` by the thing you want. Finally, we perform the definition. The extra set of braces is to prevent the optional argument from terminating too early (when seeing `##1]`). We double hash because somewhere in the middle of all this ted stores the final action into a control sequence.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{ted}
\Substitute*[{\gdef\@chapter[##1]##2}]{\@chapter[#1]{#2}}%
{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}}%
{\let\f@rtocold\f@rtoc%
 \def\f@rtoc{\uppercase\expandafter{\f@rtocold}}%
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{One}
This is chapter 1.
\appendix
\chapter{Alpha}
This is appendix A.
\end{document}
```